# how to send event when one button clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, swift3

I've created UIAlertView that has 2 buttons positive button and negative button. 
AlertView is viewcontroller as well.

I am opening AlertVC from Main viewController.

Here is my AlertVC

```
class AlertVC: UIViewController {

    var transitioner : CAVTransitioner


    @IBOutlet weak var alertPositiveBtn: IFOButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var alertNegativeBtn: IFOButton!

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        self.transitioner = CAVTransitioner()
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        self.transitioningDelegate = self.transitioner
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }



    @IBAction func postiveBtnPressed(_ sender: IFOButton) {

    }


    @IBAction func negativeBtnPressed(_ sender: IFOButton) {

    }


    @IBAction func closeBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What I want: I want MainViewController somehow detect which button pressed negative or positive.

Is anyone can tell me how could I do this?

***UPDATE: after using delegate pattern***

```
@IBAction func positiveBtnPressed(_ sender: IFOButton) {
    delegate?.positiveBtnPressed(onAlertVC: self)
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func negativeBtnPressed(_ sender: IFOButton) {
    delegate?.negativeBtnPressed(onAlertVC: self)
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is what I did on MainViewController

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, AlertVCDelegate
```

and here is my functions

```
func positiveBtnPressed(onAlertVC: IFOAlertVC) {
    print("Pos")
    }
    func negativeBtnPressed(onAlertVC: IFOAlertVC) {
    print("Neg")}
```

It still not being called.

Comment: please give the tag value alertPositiveBtn and alertNegativeBtn and  you can pass this tag value on you controller

Comment: You can use `delegate/protocol` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a textbook example of the [delegate pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Add a protocol to your AlertVC:

```
protocol AlertVCDelegate : class {
    func positiveBtnPressed(onAlertVC: AlertVC)
    func negativeBtnPressed(onAlertVC: AlertVC)
}
```

Then create a `weak` property in your AlertVC class and pass the button presses to it:

```
class AlertVC : UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: AlertVCDelegate?
    ...
    @IBAction func postiveBtnPressed(_ sender: IFOButton) {
        delegate?.positiveBtnPressed(onAlertVC: self)
    }


    @IBAction func negativeBtnPressed(_ sender: IFOButton) {
        delegate?.negativeBtnPressed(onAlertVC: self)
    }
}
```

Implement the `AlertVCDelegate` protocol in your `MainViewController`, and set the `delegate` when you present the `AlertVC` from your `MainViewController`.

If you present the alert vc from a segue, use the `prepare(for: sender:)` method to set the `MainViewController` as the delegate.

Comment: @David Ganster thank you for your answer. I did exactly what you say but function on MainViewController not being called. Is there anything could I miss? See my updated question plz

Comment: Did you make sure to set the `delegate` when presenting the alertVC? Add a breakpoint to your alert controller's `positive/negativeBtnPressed()` methods to verify that they are getting called and `delegate` isn't nil.

Comment: @DavidGanster I did. check my updated question and you will see. I set breakpoint on AlertVC it being called but when the dialog was closed, on MainViewController this function not being called at all.

Comment: @pmb You didn't show that you set the delegate anywhere, only that you implemented the protocol. Can you post the code where you set `myAlertVC.delegate = self` in `MainViewController`?

Comment: @DavidGanster I didn't set that I forgot it. Now it working great. Thank you very much. I marked at it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to CTRL + Drag the button from your app Storyboard to their own method.

Your *IFOButton* should be an UIButton derived class (inheritance).

Even you only need one method to do that

```
@IBAction internal func handleButtonTap(_ sendder: UIButton) -> Void
{
    if sender === alertPositiveBtn
    {
         // Do something positive here
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something negative here
    }
}
```